# How do I perfom a multiplication in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with a view that has the **BIRTH_DATE** and the **RETIRE_AGE**. The **RETIRE_AGE** is different for every staff. I want to calculate the **RETIRE_DATE** on each row.
I have this in my query:

```
"ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, RETIRE_AGE * 12) AS RETIRE_DATE"
```

The above doesn't work. How do I multiply the retire age that is of type NUMBER(2,0) by 12 to get the total months?

Comment: Well it should work

Comment: It is working for me when I tried in my Oracle 12C.. Select  date,ADD_MONTHS(date, 30*12)
from table;

Comment: Because you have it enclosed in quotes?  What error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to be correct based on details provided. Please refer the demo with example for full solution @https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a14aef4615cde58067fe05854b6b74fe